# Apache RewriteCond - how to convert them to nginx rewrite rules?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Following [Simple REST server in php](http://jacwright.com/250/simple-rest-server-in-php-supports-json-amf/#url-rewrite) tutorial i wat to set up rewrite rules for it. The only problem is that i have nginx

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried something like this

```
location / { 
rewrite ^/api/$ /api/index.php last;
rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php last; 
}
```

but REST server returns

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
 }
```

}

i guess it have something to do with missing RuleCond but i have no idea how to convert them.

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Check_IF_File_Exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to abstract from concrete rules and understand what they means. This Apache config means if required file or folder exists — serve them, otherwise serve `index.php`. In nginx we use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files) directive for that.

If I understand correctly, you need this in `/api/` folder, so here is idea of config:

```
index index.php;

location /api/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # PHP rules
}
```